# How to launch an app after call ending?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I came to wp development from android - so I'm still thinking in android way. may be it's a problem.

So.

I want to create an application which starts every time user ends a call.
Is there any way to listen to the "call ended" event?

In android it's easy to implement (using service which launches an activity) - but is there any way to do the same in windows phone (at least in wp8)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "call ended" event in Windows Phone as of the current SDK.

Windows Phone apps run on a closed environment, so certain functions are closed for the generic developers, as the one you're inquiring!